# Duplicity not writing to a pre-existing S3 bucket

Tags: backup, amazon-s3, duplicity

I'm trying to backup a directory to a pre-existing Amazon S3 bucket using the following command:

```
duplicity --no-encryption system/ s3+http://MY_BUCKET_NAME/backup
```

However, I'm getting the following error consistently:

```
S3CreateError: S3CreateError: 409 Conflict
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou</Code><Message>Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it.</Message><BucketName>vacationlabs</BucketName><RequestId>3C1B8C49469E3374</RequestId><HostId>4dU1TKf3Td6R0yvG9MaLKCYvQfwaCpdM8FUcv53aIOh0LeJ6wtVHHduPSTqjDwt0</HostId></Error>
```

1. The S3 bucket is empty and does NOT have the `backup` directory
2. The bucket is in Singapore region

Answer (score 12):

Duplicity also supports Amazon S3 URLs in this format:

```
s3://host/bucket_name[/prefix]
```

where `host` is the S3 endpoint for your region, which you can find in [Amazon's list of endpoints](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region).

In your case, the URL you want is:

```
s3://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/MY_BUCKET_NAME/backup
```

Note that:

- Duplicity can still only create buckets in the US Standard and EU regions, which means you'll need to manually create the bucket (which you already have).
- For regions other than US Standard, you will want to have Duplicity use Amazon's "new style" subdomain bucket addressing, by adding `--s3-use-new-style` to your Duplicity command line.

Comment: With s3+http I got duplicity error "Access Denied". Got fixed with s3://host/bucket. Used same IAM user / policy. Go figure....

Answer (score 2):

@mgorven is right, and I'm going to try to get this fixed properly. If you'd like to see this fixed, please mark yourself affected and subscribe at https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1003159

The `s3://<region>/<bucket>` syntax doesn't work (any more), you can only do `s3+http://<bucket>` which uses us-east-1 or eu-west-1 if you specify `--s3-european-buckets`. You can't get to any other regions.

Comment: I encountered this too and I agree it should be handled properly. There is also a Zone-Infrequent S3 class now that could be used if one wanted to.

Comment: endpoints like `s3://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name` are working fine in 0.7.17, haven't tried current version 0.7.19

Comment: I found that `s3://s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name` works but only if I don't also say `--s3-use-multiprocessing`. With this flag present, we get the UnsupportedBackendScheme error which seems wrong and confusing. Hope this helps someone. On version 0.8.19.

Comment: I confirm the need for http: `s3+http://mybucket`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [duplicity manpage](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html#sect10), it looks like it only supports the US and EU S3 regions. I'd guess that it's talking to the US endpoint, detects that the bucket doesn't exist in the US region, and then tries to create it and fails.

Try creating a bucket in the US or EU region and test whether that works (using `--s3-european-buckets` if appropriate). If that does work and you really want to use the Singapore region, you'll have to hack Duplicity to support it.